# What are psychiatric effects of this herbal medicine?

Tags: medications

Its is called **Khamira Gaozaban Ambri**.What could be its psychiatric effects, is it effective against phobias and fears? And is there any possible side effect of using this with Ginkgo Biloba?[image]